# assign object as key value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tyring to do something like this:

```
this.slides = {$('#Page_1') : null,
               $('#Page_2') : null,
               $('#Page_3') : null};
```

**Why am I doing this, or what advantage do I gain?**
I dont want to use jquery selectors throughout class.

---

### A Solution:

```
this.slides = [{"key": $('#Page_1'), "value": null},
               {"key": $('#Page_2'), "value": null},
               {"key": $('#Page_3'), "value": null}];
```

**Limitation:**

> The problem with this approach is that you have to iterate through the
>   whole object each time you want to approach this. You should use the
>   id as identifier, this is much more efficient. – Christoph

Comment: this is nonsense - the key is meant to be the identifier, you can't use an object for that. Also i cannot think of a usecase where this might be useful.

Comment: @Asad i guess i thought becuase each object was uniquely identifyable this might be possible.

Comment: @Christoph: no need to be so harsh, OP is clearly just trying to learn.

Comment: correct, but a key is supposed to be for data retrieval, not for the data itself. the value (which you are setting to null) is supposed to hold the data, in this case your DOM element.

Comment: @Christoph: Oh, Object-Object maps could be very useful; JavaScript currently lacks them (though there is [a proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:weak_maps)).

Comment: You should probably be using [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and not an object.

Comment: @epascarello makes an excelent point, with this solution you'd leak a bunch of memory if #Page_1 was removed from the dom no?

Comment: i just don't see how you'd use this? Whats the advantage over just using the id name as the key? Seems like you are re-inventing the wheel and making more work for yourself? See @dweeves 's answer.

Comment: @j_mcnally i want to use objects so i dont need to use jquery selectors throughout class.

Comment: @DanKanze i think we need to see more of your code to help you then, based on what you sent us, this seems illogical. Im sure there is a way to refactor it, without all these gymnastics

Comment: @epascarello how would I assign and retrieve data from a `.data()` jquery object too `this.slides`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try a structure like this:

```
this.slides = [{"key": $('#Page_1'), "value": null},
               etc.];
```

Or does that break your need for using an object?

Of course, when iterating it, you'd have to use logic like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
    var key = this.slides[i].key;
    var value = this.slides[i].value;
}
```

Comment: @DanKanze Cool, well I just added a quick note on how to access each item (I'm sure you would've known how to anyways)

Comment: Leveraging the underscore library can make dealing with this type of schema easier to deal with.

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/ specifically, pluck, find, etc. If you need to look an object up by some sort of filter. The collection methods are very useful.

Comment: @DanKanze The problem with this approach is that you have to iterate through the whole object each time you want to approach this. You should use the `id` as identifier, this is much more efficient. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: @Christoph It completely depends on what the OP is using this for. Either approach could be correct, as we don't know exactly how this is being used or the way it's being accessed. Either solution is perfectly fine and could work better than the other.

Comment: That is true, but by losing the ability to directly access the elements, I would find this solution not optimal for most usecases. Nontheless a working and valid solution I admit;)

Comment: @Christoph Yeah but the fact that you assume the `id` is something that will available the in the OP's context might not be right. Also, with your solution, you don't allow for a value, like the OP showed in their original object (where each happens to be `null`) - not sure if the value was actually important though, but that's what I was working towards.

Answer (score 3):

No, keys must be literals. you could use a property of your object.

Comment: I edited my answer, I guess a literal would be the best way to put it, since a key could also be an integer? Im not sure what the best term is.

Comment: I think literal is just fine, I'm not sure either - probably the ES-spec has the answer but I'm too lazy too look it up -.-

Answer (score 2):

If your processing is based on the this.slides content, why not use the id as key ? since they are also meant to be "unique" otherwise you would break the DOM.
So i would suggest something like

```
this.slides = {'#Page_1':null,'#Page_2':null,'#Page_3':null};
```

And a very light modification of your processing of this.slides

Comment: i want to use objects so i dont need to use jquery selectors throughout class. thankyou though.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use objects as keys, only plain literals. I'd suggest a structure like this:

```
this.slides = { 'Page_1' : $('#Page_1'),
                'Page_2' : $('#Page_2')
                'Page_3' : $('#Page_3')};
```

This way you can use the `id` of the elements to easily access the according jQuery-Object. (You can omit the quotes for the keys.)

```
slides.Page_1
// or
slides['Page_1']
```

now gives you the according jQuery Object.